# Deploying QML app

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, qml

I made a litle QML app that I have to deploy on windows.

I compiled it on release mode.

I'm not use to deploy on windows and after I add a lot of dll next to my file (thanks to dependency walker), it doesn't start.

I add another dll that wasn't needed (apparently) and the app finally start.

But it launch an empty window.

What did I do wrong ? How can I make it to work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your app must ship with the QML files and all needed icons.
The most simple solution is to put all qml and icons files in a Qt Resource file (.qrc), and then simply do a C++ launcher that loads a QQuickView from the qrc :

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    QGuiApplication app (argc, argv);
    QQuickView view     (QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.setTitle       (QObject::tr("My App"));
    view.setResizeMode  (QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.showNormal     ();
    return app.exec     ();
}
```

Then just compile the whole thing, your QML, SVG, PNG files will be compiled into the C++ program so you will just have to ship the binary without caring about resources !